# ROR return JSON with 406 Not Acceptable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When we return JSON output using `render :json =>@profiles`, the
output will return the required results with a 406 error. How can
avoid that '406 Not Acceptable' error ?

Comment: Can you provide the controller code you're using?

Comment: A picture is worth 1000 words but some code will get your question answered!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm more than sure that you have [this problem](http://thesystemisntdown.blogspot.com/2009/12/rails-error-406.html).

Explanations:

Say your controller only returns json answers

```
def action
  # call
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: results }
  end
end
```

This will return the json as soon as:

- `/path_to_action.json` is called
- `/path_to_action` is called with headers `Content-Type:application/json;` and probably some other header types (Eg. `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest`)

Otherwise, it returns a `406 Not Acceptable` error.

To avoid the issue, if your controller only returns json, write:

```
def action
  # call
  render json: results
end
```

otherwise, use `/path_to_action.json` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Doug's answer and for whoever might still stumble upon this problem,

This problem can also occur more specifically when a controller method used for POST http requests renders a JSON instead of redirecting. If this method has a before_action AND that before action tries to "redirect_to" instead of rendering a JSON as it was initially intended to do so, the error pops.

To fix it just make sure that your before_action for that method also renders a response instead of trying to redirect it.

Example:

```
before_action :require_configuration_training

def locations_post
  response = 'hey'
  render json: response, status: 200
end


def require_configuration_training
 response = 'hi'
 # Correct below:
 render json: response, status: 200

 # Wrong and will raise error below:
 # redirect_to another_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when i had `before_action :authenticate_user!` on the controller action, but was calling this from an unauthenticated page.

The page itself was attempting to issue a redirect.

Authenticating the user, or removing the `before_action` solved it for me.